# Query orderable by number of day between two dates

Tags: mysql

I've an event planner `mysql` database and I'm trying to get a report of city table to show all cities ordered by the number of days for each event.

for example some records are:

```
event_id - city_id - start - end
1 - 88 - 2019-01-01 - 2019-01-05
2 - 89 - 2019-02-01 2019-02-03
3 - 90 - 2019-03-01 2019-03-04
4 - 88 - 2019-01-06 - 2019-01-07
```

The report could be:

```
city_id - days
  88    -  7
  90    -  4
  89    -  3
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and attach what have you tried so far?

Comment: is there always a - between the dates **1 - 88 - 2019-01-01 - 2019-01-05** In some rows the is no -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it with a query like this:

```
SELECT event_id , city_id, SUM( DATEDIFF( `end`,`start`)+1 )  as days
FROM sample
GROUP BY city_id
order by SUM( DATEDIFF( `end`,`start`) +1  ) DESC;
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [test]> select * from sample;

+----------+---------+------------+------------+
| event_id | city_id | start      | end        |
+----------+---------+------------+------------+
|        1 |      88 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-05 |
|        2 |      89 | 2019-02-01 | 2019-02-03 |
|        3 |      90 | 2019-03-01 | 2019-03-04 |
|        4 |      88 | 2019-01-06 | 2019-01-07 |
+----------+---------+------------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.229 sec)

MariaDB [test]> 
MariaDB [test]> SELECT event_id , city_id, SUM( DATEDIFF( `end`,`start`)+1 )  as days
    -> FROM sample
    -> GROUP BY city_id
    -> order by SUM( DATEDIFF( `end`,`start`) +1  ) DESC;
+----------+---------+------+
| event_id | city_id | days |
+----------+---------+------+
|        1 |      88 |    7 |
|        3 |      90 |    4 |
|        2 |      89 |    3 |
+----------+---------+------+
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [test]>
```

Comment: thank you so much! I just change order by days instead of repeat sum function.

Comment: @Watanabe77 - you must have the sum function if you have more then 1 time the same city_id to have a correct result

Answer (score 0):

use below query -

```
select 
   event_id, city_id, DATEDIFF(end, start) as days
 from 
   table_name
 order by DATEDIFF(end, start) desc
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? How can this query return an ordered list?

Comment: I just wrote the query to get number of days between 2 dates. yes for ordering we have to add order by clause as "order by DATEDIFF(end, start) desc"